# Is it still possible to authenticate and authorize 20.04 against an unencrypted LDAP server?

Tags: 20.04, ldap, openldap, sssd

20.04/'Focal Fossa' uses [sssd](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-sssd) to handle authentication, authorization, and user and group information against LDAP.

Nevertheless, [sssd does not support authentication over an *unencrypted* channel](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/sssd-ldap.5.html).

I have a very small network with an ldap server which is part of a [NAS](https://www.qnap.com/tr-tr/how-to/tutorial/article/how-to-use-the-built-in-ldap-server-of-qnap-nas-for-user-management/). This server does not support encryption. And yes, I could setup a modern ldap server in a LXC on this NAS. (If I had the knowledge...)

Much easier for me would be, making 20.04 working with unencrypted ldap server again.

Do any of you know if and how this works?

Comment: [`nslcd`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/nslcd.8.html) seems to be present. I don't think it has similar security measures.

Comment: which maker of NAS are you using ?

Comment: QNAP (Just click on the NAS link in my question...)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru)'s help I made it work.

After the installation of [nscld](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/nslcd.8.html) `# apt-get install -y nslcd` you should execute `# dpkg-reconfigure -plow nslcd`, even if [nslcd](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/nslcd.8.html) already asked questions during the installation.
This saves you from having to edit `/etc/nslcd.conf` by hand.